# Assigning fixed ggplot2 shapes based on dynamic set of values

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

I am working on a Power BI project and am making some R visuals. One of the visuals is a scatterplot. Each point has a categorical value ("Yes", "No"). I am choosing to represent these categories via shape. Sometimes the user will query the data in such a way that there will be only one category per point. I want my "Yes" shape to remain unique only for "Yes" values, and my "No" shape to remain unique only for "No" values.

My code:

```
ggplot(data = dataset) + 
    geom_point(data = dataset, aes(x= value1 y=value2, shape = YesNo_column) + 
    scale_shape_manual(name="", values = c(20, 0))
```

I want "Yes" points always to have shape "20", and "No" points always to have shape "0". If the user queries the data to only show "No" points, then my code will assign shape "20" to those points, instead of shape "0".

EDIT: I have just made some sample data to show my issue:

```
query1 <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4 | mtcars$cyl == 6,]

query1$YesNo_column <- "blah"

query1[query1$cyl==4,]$YesNo_column <- "Yes"
query1[query1$cyl==6,]$YesNo_column <- "No"


ggplot(query1, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, shape=YesNo_column)) + 
  geom_point()+
  scale_shape_manual(name="",values = c(20, 0))


query2 <- query1[query1$YesNo_column == "Yes",]

ggplot(query2, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, shape=YesNo_column)) + 
  geom_point()+
  scale_shape_manual(name="",values = c(20, 0))
```

As you can see, the shapes are not fixed to the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `yes` and `no` are encoded as a factor and simply use `DROP = FALSE`

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- tibble(
  x = rnorm(20, 1.0, 0.3),
  y = rnorm(20, 1.5, 0.4),
  response = sample(c("yes", "no"), replace = TRUE, size = 20)
) %>% 
  mutate(response = as.factor(response))


ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = response)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="", values = c(20, 0), drop = FALSE)

mydata %>%
  filter(response == "yes") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, shape = response)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="", values = c(20, 0), drop = FALSE)
```

[image: First]

[image: Second]